# Can I have Apllication Menu on topbar Like MacOS Finder bar in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, macosx, top-bar

Hi so can I have the Topbar look linke MacOS finder bar and **have all the options like `File Edit Veiw Go` and etc according to the application**

I want to actually change this to

[image: Ubuntu Top Bar]

Somthing like this

[image: MacOS Finder Ba]

I want all the windowe options on topbar and want remove it from the application just like MacOs

I actually know a [Extention named as Gnome Global Application Menu](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1250/gnome-global-application-menu/) but dont work so please dont recommend this extention

so thanks in advance

Comment: Global Menu works very well in Kubuntu, Xubuntu and Ubuntu MATE (it is against the "GNOME Vision", and does not work with GNOME Shell). If you are willing to use those desktop environments, I can write it into a detailed answer. [This](https://imgur.com/zhmXwoj.png) is global menu in XFCE, and this is [KDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zf22.png)

Comment: For MATE check https://guide.ubuntu-mate.org/#panel-layouts-cupertino .